# [IOS]loading imageurl into tableview uiimage

Tags: ios, xcode

i am new to IOS.
i have an array of imageurl which is needed to be stored in the uimage tableview
Right now i have a problem.

I have this code

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[thumbnails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

I know it wont display anything as I have to do something to make the imageview load the imageurl.
Could anyone guide me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use :

`view_Image.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url_Img_FULL]]];`

Comment: Hi, Do i put it like this ? 
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfURL:[thumbnails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

Comment: I am getting [__NSArrayM length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fbe0b49d7e0